# Can't make img and text vertically center

Tags: html, css

I don't know why but I can't make my image and text to be vertically align.

```
<div class="adress">
   <img src="#">My adress
</div>
```

If I use display:flex and then align-items: center, it's not work, vertical align doesn't work too (if I set display: table").

Maybe I am something missing?

```css
.adresa {line-height: 1.4; padding-bottom: 30px;}
.adresa img {float: left; width: 40px; margin-right: 15px !important;}
```

```html
<div class="adresa">
<img src="https://image.ibb.co/g9yTN9/adresa.png" />Nušlova 2271/7<br>
158 00 Praha 5
</div>
<div class="adresa">
<img src="https://image.ibb.co/g9yTN9/adresa.png" />7227336777
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please improve code snippet. It is possible to use a placeholder image or a stockimage

Comment: I copy pasted your code into a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/pdhyja7s/) and it worked well for me. Can you provide more details ?

Comment: Oh, I make mistake to put the code to img, not all div, thanks! :-) So sorry for Your time :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
.adress{
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.adress img{
    display:flex; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I don't see no any explanation that help the OP to use your solution, at least provide a runnable snippet. Btw the class-name is `adresa` not `adress`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `flexbox` by wrapping text to `p`

```css
.adresa {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.adresa p {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="adresa">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/g9yTN9/adresa.png" />
  <p>Nušlova 2271/7<br>158 00 Praha 5</p>
</div>
<div class="adresa">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/g9yTN9/adresa.png" />
  <p>7227336777</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
<div class="adress">
  <span><img src="blah.jpg" /></span>
  <span>My adress</span>
</div>

div {
  display: table;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

here is the fiddle sample demo - http://jsfiddle.net/oraf8jg5/

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox works fine.

```css
.adresa {
  line-height: 1.4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.adresa img {
  max-width: 40px;
  margin-right: 15px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="adresa">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/g9yTN9/adresa.png" />Nušlova 2271/7<br> 158 00 Praha 5
</div>
<div class="adresa">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/g9yTN9/adresa.png" />7227336777
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it's work perfectly

```
.adresa {
  line-height: 1.4;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.adresa img {
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 15px !important;
}
```